# What exceptions exist to increase the range of Magic Missile?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Under most circumstances, the [Magic Missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile) spell has a range of 120'.

I have heard of some (possible?) exception-examples:  Sorcerers can double range (once?), a familiar using a *wand of magic missiles* might work (range?). I am not even sure how these exceptions work - or how many others exist.

Any range extending option that is from a 5e published, hardcover text is fair game (Tasha's / Xanathars' / Mordenkainen's / etc.).

**Reason for request:** low level players wish to attack a *close-range = deadly* target (*Bodak*, CR6).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Sorcerer: Distant Spell Metamagic

Your best option for *magic missile* is going to be the sorcerer’s Distant Spell Metamagic:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.

#### Wizard, Order of Scribes: Manifest Mind

The Order of Scribes wizard has a feature that can get you a significant increase to the range of your spells, Manifest Mind:

> Whenever you cast a wizard spell on your turn, you can cast it as if you were in the spectral mind’s space, instead of your own, using its senses. You can do so a number of times per day equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

It can be up to 300 feet away from you, and you can move it 30 feet on a turn using your bonus action.

#### What doesn't work, that at first glance looks like it should.

Notably, the feat Spell Sniper *does not help*, as Spell Sniper states:

> When you cast a spell that *requires you to make an attack roll*, the spell’s range is doubled.

Since *magic missile* does not require an attack roll, its range is not doubled by Spell Sniper; but it will help with any other spell that requires an attack roll, so may still be worth it.